# Execute Java based Selenium WebDriver Test in Apache Jmeter

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to execute (I would like to extend later) my first Java based Selenium test in Apache Jmeter but I got an error message in the log section:

Here is my simple code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:\\DEVTOOLS\\PERFORMANCE_TEST\\FIREFOX_GECKO_DRIVER\\geckodriver.exe")
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

String url="https://www.google.com/")
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.close();
```

This is the error:

```
2020-06-30 14:52:20,702 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-06-30 14:52:20,702 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-06-30 14:52:20,703 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-06-30 14:52:20,710 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2020-06-30 14:52:20,710 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2020-06-30 14:52:20,710 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-06-30 14:52:20,710 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2020-06-30 14:52:20,710 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-06-30 14:52:20,710 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-06-30 14:52:20,711 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2020-06-30 14:52:20,719 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Firefox . . . '' Encountered "WebDriver" at line 5, column 1.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Firefox . . . '' at line number 5
javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Firefox . . . '' Encountered "WebDriver" at line 5, column 1.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Firefox . . . '' at line number 5
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:82) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:224) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
2020-06-30 14:52:20,719 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2020-06-30 14:52:20,719 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2020-06-30 14:52:20,720 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-06-30 14:52:20,720 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

I don't know exactly why is happening because every jars are copied into:
Apache Jmeter lib folder and lib/ext/ folder as well.

I would like to leave the WDS.Sampler if it possible. This is the reason why I started using SR223Sampler.

**UPDATES:**

Here is the final solution what I have. It works as I expected.

```html
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:\\DEVTOOLS\\PERFORMANCE_TEST\\FIREFOX_GECKO_DRIVER\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

String expectedTitle = "Google";
String actualTitle = "";
String baseUrl = "https://google.com";

driver.get(baseUrl);

actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
    System.out.println("Test Passed!");
    } else {
    System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }

Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to a **malformed** [url](/questions/tagged/url) as a result of a *syntax* issue in the line:

```
String url="https://www.google.com/")
```

You need to pass the proper *url* and replace the line as:

```
String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
```

Then pass the *url* string to the `get()` method as follows:

```
driver.get(baseUrl);
```

Additionally, on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) systems the drive is **`C:`** (in uppercase) instead of *`c:`* (in lowercase). Effectively, the line would be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\DEVTOOLS\\PERFORMANCE_TEST\\FIREFOX_GECKO_DRIVER\\geckodriver.exe")
```

Comment: Ohh thanks. It is a shame from my side :'(. I appreciate your help!
There was one more issue, namely the ; missed from the System.setProperty line.

Comment: @Imi There's nothing shame in asking a question when we are out of ideas. Have a great learning ahead.